# Syntastic doesn't find C header files despite Configuring

Tags: vimrc, plugin-syntastic

I have configured the following properly in my .vimrc in the root folder of a project to keep syntastic settings Project specific.

But still Syntastic throws errors saying "No Such File or Directory"

**Directory Structure**

```
--Project    
    |---include
         |---foo.h    
    |---src
         |---foo.c
    |---.vimrc
```

**.vimrc Contents**

```
let g:syntastic_c_include_dirs = ['/home/pydi.k/Project/include/']
```

foo.c shows a "foo.h no such file or directory"

Bottom Line - I want to configure syntastic so that it looks for custom made header files at locations I point to.

Comment: Why do you think adding two empty directories to `g:syntastic_c_include_dirs` will accomplish anything useful?

Comment: @lcd047 I mentioned properly referring to directory Locations starting with /home/username/directorylocation was mentioned.

Comment: Right, you did.  What I'm asking is why do you think that's the "proper" way of doing it.

Comment: https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues/70   I have referred to this link to understand it as the correct of way doing it. Please suggest, if you i need to add other options as well to get syntastic working properly.

Comment: @lcd047 In additioon to that, I have tried the following as well by having seperate config file for syntastic and configuring it. Reference - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622992/including-header-files-recursively-for-syntastic. I am guessing that i am missing something fundamental.

Comment: Excellent.  Now, can you tell the difference between what you did and what those other people did?

Comment: Please update your post in a way so that we can try to reproduce this problem. In this case, this would mean a minimal vimrc file (which only loads this plugin, and sets some basic settings) and a few C files which show the problem ...

Comment: @lcd047 I still am not able to find a difference that might help solve this.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Have edited the question to reproduce the problem!

Comment: @lcd047 Me myself haven't used a empty string as a include directory, I have just put that and expected it to be self explanatory that i filled proper directory paths.

Comment: What checker are you using?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a a checker.

Comment: Did you read the manual?  Syntastic doesn't do any syntax checks by itself, it just runs a number of external checkers against your files and shows you the results.  You're supposed to do some minimal configuration before using it, such as add the [recommended settings](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic#user-content-3-recommended-settings) to your vimrc, and set `g:syntastic_c_checkers`.

Comment: @lcd047 Turns out it was not required to configure those c checkers. The problem was that the .vimrc in the root directory was not picked by my vim even though I was launching it from the root directory of the project. Now, all i need to do is to ensure vim to pick that .vimrc which solves all the problems.

Comment: _Turns out it was not required to configure those c checkers._ - You are.  Don't bother reporting any problems if you don't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25782/discussion-between-b1tchacked-and-lcd047).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is **not in Configuring Syntastic** but rather letting Vim **load the `.vimrc`** file in the  root directory of your project. The following will solve the problem and ensure that you **load the `.vimrc`** before Syntastic checks for errors.

- After loading vim, explicitly run the command `:so location/to/.vimrc`
- Configuring your central `.vimrc` to load the local `.vimrc` file from wherever you are launching vim would be a headache as you should carefully always launch it from the root of the project. Instead add this line to the central `.vimrc`: `so .vimrc`
- Use the plugin [localrc](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3393).